# Mobile interface displays award bounty button beside your own answers

Tags: bug, status-completed, bounties, mobile-web

It is not possible to award yourself a bounty, but the button to do so is still included in the mobile interface (left). It should not be there; it is not included in the non-mobile interface (right):

> [image]
>           [image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will be fixed in the next build.